# get an item only after scroll function finish

Tags: java, android, view, scroll

I am working with Navigation menu view and I am scrolling it programmatically and then get a Y position of its item.
But the code that get the item positions is running immediately after the list (using the layout manager) starts to scroll and when it haven't finished to scroll and change the positions yet.
How can I do the rest of code after "**scrollToPositionWithOffset**" wait the end of the scroll action to run?

Here's my code:

```
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) navigationView.getChildAt(0);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager();

    layoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(4, 0);

     //it should wait the line above run completely to can run too
    mImage.animate().y(navView.getChildAt(4).getY());
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a  scroll listener that listens for the Scrolling state to change to idle..  See below.

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
  @Override
   public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {

     mImage.animate().y(navView.getChildAt(4).getY());
     recyclerView.removeOnScrollListener(this);
    }

  }

}

   layoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(4, 0);
```

Comment: This seems to not work =/. The method is never called after firing `scrollToPositionWithOffset`.

Answer (score 0):

On researching i found this :

```
 final LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false) {
                @Override
                public void onLayoutChildren(final Recycler recycler, final State state) {
                    super.onLayoutChildren(recycler, state);
                    //TODO if the items are filtered, considered hiding the fast scroller here
                    final int firstVisibleItemPosition = findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
                    if (firstVisibleItemPosition != 0) {
                        // this avoids trying to handle un-needed calls
                        if (firstVisibleItemPosition == -1)
                            //not initialized, or no items shown, so hide fast-scroller
                            mFastScroller.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        return;
                    }
                    final int lastVisibleItemPosition = findLastVisibleItemPosition();
                    int itemsShown = lastVisibleItemPosition - firstVisibleItemPosition + 1;
                    //if all items are shown, hide the fast-scroller
                    mFastScroller.setVisibility(mAdapter.getItemCount() > itemsShown ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
                }
            };
```

The good thing here is that it works well and will handle even keyboard being shown/hidden.

The bad thing is that it gets called on cases that aren't interesting (meaning it has false positives), but it's not as often as scrolling events, so it's good enough for me.

Comment: Thanks, but in my case, sometimes all items aren't shown because I don't need go to the end of a list, but I need to know if the scroll worked and stopped, it doesn't need to be in the final of the list, but always when the scroll worked and stopped.